# How to position absolute positioned div in floated parent?

Tags: css, html

I tried to position  a `arrow` div in the edge of floated div `right`, so i given absolute position to `arrow` and left to 0.

I know absolute position won't be in the static flow and it is different from others. even thought it should obey the left value according to their parent, isn't it?

Why in the [js](http://jsfiddle.net/3tAnA/) the `arrow` is not placed at the border of `right` div rather it placing in the outer div

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="right">
    <div id="arrow">
      arr
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px solid green;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:2px solid green;

}
#arrow {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code within the question itself.

Comment: Parent should have `Position:relative`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do position: relative; on its parent with id="right".

[Relavant link on position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: SO with floated parent element absolute position won't work, that what are you proposing? Can i use position absolute in parent too in this case it is `id=right`

Comment: Yes, position denies your float. You can use position absolute on its parent but you then need to use position relative on id="wrapper".
Point is, when you absolute position something it needs to have some parent with position too.

Comment: I added a link, read that part about absolute position, it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#right {
    ...
    position:relative;
}
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/3tAnA/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3tAnA/2/

I changed #arrow to

```
right:0;
```

instead of left.

and added position:relative; to the #right.

Comment: How float and position:relative are working? I heard Both position and float cannot be used at the same time. Just want to know

Comment: They're on different elements.  I made #right a relative position, even though it doesn't make any effect on #right, it makes anything positioned absolutely inside of it, relative to #right instead of the body of the page.

Comment: `#arrow` is already child of `#right` then how will it place according to body of the page. It(`#arrow`) should place according to its containing div `#right` which has `float:right`. Thanks @Dan Goodspeed

Comment: If something is positioned absolute, it is positioned to its closest position:relative; ancestor.  So you have to make its parent position:relative if you want to position it inside that… otherwise, it just positions itself relative to the body.

Comment: Oh i see, so whenever i give a position absolute to some div it will consider a nearest div with position relative as parent or else it will consider the 1st containing div or else body of the document. Am i clear? @Dan Goodspeed

Comment: I think so.  Read Chris Coyier's article - http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/